# Change function parameters color

Tags: colors, visual-studio-code, themes, color-scheme

I'm trying to import my custom color scheme from Sublime to VSCode. I'm almost done but the only thing that I can't change is the color of parameters for a function.

[image]

`$timeOut` stays white between the parenthesis, no matter the scope I try. I tried `meta.function.parameter.typehinted.php`, `meta.function.parameters.php`.

The only one that "works" is `variable.other.php`. But unfortunately, it changes all the variables' color, not only the parameters' one.

Here is what I get when inspecting the TM Scopes:

[image]

Is there any way to change only the color of the function parameters?

Comment: what color theme is this btw?

Comment: @AlyM.Aly it's mine, based on the Material theme. You can find it here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kinoute.hivacruz-theme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After writing an issue on Github about it, a contributor gave me the correct scopes to use to change the color of the function parameters:

```
        {
        "name": "Parameters inside PHP function",
        "scope": [
            "meta.function.parameter variable",
            "meta.function.parameter punctuation.definition.variable.php"
        ],
        "settings": {
            "fontStyle": "italic",
            "foreground": "#ff8e30"
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your user.settings json file, reload and you're good to go. You can set the color in foreground part. Also you can change the scope to `meta.function-call` too, for changing colors in function call.

```
"textMateRules": [
  {
    "scope": "meta.function",
    "settings": {
      "fontStyle": "",
      "foreground": "#fbff0d"
    }
  }
]
```

By the way nice color scheme. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, your code changes the color of the parenthesis, not the color of the parameters inside the parenthesis :(

Comment: maybe it doesnt work with php files. Like i had tried the same in a c++ file and it worked just fine. Had you tried all scopes that you got while inspecting the php function?

Comment: Yes, most of them only change the color of the parenthesis or do nothing. Maybe there is something wrong with the PHP TM Scopes in VSCode because none of the color themes I installed seems to style function parameters differently than a normal variable in PHP.